# A question regarding the power of a sinus function.

Tags: trigonometry, notation

My calculus book says the following:

$\sin^{n}{x}$ is short for $(\sin{x})^n$, $n\neq -1$.

This is obviously trivial, however I don't get it why it says  $n\neq -1$. The above condition should for $n=-1$, right?

Thank you very much for your help!
Regards,
Charlie

Comment: $\sin^{-1} x $ is also short for $\arcsin x$.

Comment: Formally, they are equal (it's like saying $a\cdot b = ab$), but generally one would write $\sin^{-1}x$ to indicate $\arcsin x$, so i guess that is the reason.

Comment: That is just a notation that can be confusing at some moment of time but any mathematical text clarifies whenever there is an ambiguity

Answer (score 3):

I would go as far as saying the notation
$$
\sin^n x = (\sin x)^n
$$
is only standard when $n$ is a *positive integer*. $\sin^{-1}$ means $\arcsin$, and I have never seen $\sin^{-2}$ or the like. It's for this very reason that people consider the $\sin^{-1}$ notation to be confusing, since it does not conform with how we interpret $\sin^n$ generally. There are other reasons this notation is illogical: strictly speaking, $\sin$ does not have an inverse, and so writing $\sin^{-1}$ is somewhat suspect to begin with. I go into more detail about this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3956309/sine-vs-sine-understanding-the-differences/3956363#3956363).

Comment: Mh, what about $(\tan x)'=\cos^{-2}x$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I've never seen that before; in my experience people write $(\tan x)' = \sec^2x$ or $(\tan x)' = 1/\cos^2x$. But perhaps this is just the convention here in the UK.

Comment: You are right, $\sec$ is handy. But when you don't want a denominator and want the cosine to appear...

Answer (score 1):

It's a tricky notation problem. Generally in mathematics, $f^{-1}(x)$ means the *functional* inverse--not literally $\frac{1}{f(x)}$. That's why there's the distinction for $n \neq -1$. Furthermore, there *is* a function for $\frac{1}{\sin(x)} = \csc(x)$ (the cosecant), same for cosine (secant), and same for tangent (cotangent).

Personally, I'm not a fan of the $\sin^{-1}(x)$ notation for the inverse sine function (for the exact reason you're asking about). When I taught calculus, I tried to convince my students that this was, indeed, a confusing notation and urged them to, instead, use $\arcsin(x)$, $\arctan(x)$, and $\arccos(x)$ for the inverses.

I will add that there is the pesky notation of $\frac{df}{dx} = f'(x)$, $\frac{d^2f}{dx^2} = f''(x)$, and so on...it's gets cumbersome at a point, i.e. $\frac{d^6f}{dx^6} = f''''''(x)$??? So the general notation is a parenthesis: $\frac{d^6f}{dx^6} = f^{(6)}(x)$.

Comment: Functional inverse vs. multiplicative inverse.

Comment: @YvesDaoust good point...fixed