# Restricting Domain and Range in Inverse Trigonometric Function

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

After an explanation of the restricted domains and ranges of inverse trigonometric functions, I.M. Gelfand's Trigonometry gives the following exercise:

*Show that $$\sin(\arccos b) = \pm \sqrt{1-b^2}$$  What determines whether we should choose the positive sign or the negative sign?*

It is my understanding that:

$b^2 + \sin^2 x = 1$

So $\sin x = \pm \sqrt{1-b^2}$.

But  $0\leq \arccos b \leq \pi$

So $-1\leq b \leq 1$

So $\sin 0 \leq \sin x \leq \sin \pi $

And $0 \leq \sin x \leq 1$.

I must be missing something because it seems to me that we would not need the ambiguous sign and the original expression should be $$\sin(\arccos b) = \sqrt{1-b^2}$$ because $\sin x$ where $x = \arccos b$ will always be positive.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think you are missing anything, the definition of $\arccos$ *I* know makes it take values in $[0,\pi]$ and so its $\sin$ is non-negative. However, I don't have access to the book: worth double-checking if the author uses different definitions for the inverse trigonometric functions (e.g. if they allow for the definition of $\arccos$ in such way so that it takes values in $[-\pi, 0]$ rather than in $[0,\pi]$).

Comment: Maybe your question as posted is the answer to Gelfand's question.

Comment: I think you are right, with the standard definitions. If they are giving b, the value of a cosine, you don't know what quadrant the original angle is in.  You don't have that angle, so, you can choose the minus sign if you are trying to describe a situation that you know is in the third or fourth quadrants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct. We can verify it in a slightly different way by noting that
$$
\sin^2 x + \cos^2x = 1
$$
and so
$$
\left|\sin x\right| = \sqrt{1-\cos^2x} \, .
$$
Hence,
\begin{align}
\left|\sin(\arccos(b))\right| &= \sqrt{1-\cos^2(\arccos(b))} \\
&= \sqrt{1-b^2} \, .
\end{align}
Because $\arccos(b) \in [0,\pi]$, we know that $\sin(\arccos b) \geq 0$. Hence, we are left with
$$
\sin(\arccos(b))=\sqrt{1-b^2} \, .
$$
The crux of solving this problem is understanding the range of the $\arccos$ function, so that we can draw this conclusion. Strictly speaking, $\arccos$ is *not* the inverse of $\cos$—rather, it is the inverse of $\operatorname{Cos}$, which is the function $f:[0,\pi] \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=\cos(x)$. On the other hand, $\cos$ is the inverse of $\arccos$, since $\arccos$ is one-to-one. It is because of this that $\cos(\arccos(x))$ is always equal to $x$, but $\arccos(\cos(x))$ might not be equal to $x$.

Comment: Cos vs. cos is beyond the scope of my education at this point, but let me ask this: is arccos not the inverse of cos because cos x is not invertible for all real numbers, but must be restricted to $[0, \pi]$?

Comment: @KateKatich: Yes, exactly. Very often people say that $\arccos$ is the inverse of $\cos$, even though this is technically not true. The function $\operatorname{Cos}$ is the same as $\cos$, except that its domain is $[0,\pi]$. Two functions are only equal if (a) they have the same domain and (b) if they have the same values. Hence, when we 'restrict the domain of $\cos$', what we are actually doing is switching our focus to a new function $\operatorname{Cos}$. So $\cos$ is not invertible—only $\operatorname{Cos}$ is.

Comment: It's somewhat sloppy to say that $\cos$ has an inverse along a restricted domain, since the 'restricted domain' version of $\cos$ is actually a different function.

Comment: @KateKatich: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3956309/sine-vs-sine-understanding-the-differences/3956363#3956363) is an answer I wrote earlier where I go into more detail about this.